# Query String Composition in Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to run a SQL "SELECT" query in Postgres from  Python using Psycopg2. I am trying to compose the query string as below, but getting error message, using psycopg2 version 2.9.

```
from psycopg2 import sql

tablename = "mytab"
schema = "public"
query = sql.SQL("SELECT table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name = {tablename} and table_schema = {schema};")
query = query.format(tablename=sql.Identifier(tablename), schema=sql.Identifier(schema))
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Error:

```
psycopg2.error.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: This message means that an error has _already_ occurred in the transaction, so the next statement cannot be executed.  You need to call `rollback()` on the connection to reset it (and of course, you should find out what had failed before and fix it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the (a bit strange) query

```sql
select table_name 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_name = 'mytab'
and table_schema = 'public';
```

`'mytab'` and `'public'` are literals, not identifiers. For comparison, `mytab` is an identifier here:

```sql
select *
from mytab;
```

Thus your `format` statement should look like this:

```py
query = query.format(tablename=sql.Literal(tablename), schema=sql.Literal(schema))
```

Note that the quoted error message is somewhat misleading as it is about executing a query other than what is shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since this query is only dealing with dynamic values it can be simplified to:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(<params>)
cursor = con.cursor()

tablename = "mytab"
schema = "public"
# Regular placeholders
query = """SELECT 
    table_name 
from 
    information_schema.tables 
where 
    table_name = %s and table_schema = %s"""

cursor.execute(query, [tablename, schema])
result = cursor.fetchone()[0]

# Named placeholders
query = """SELECT 
    table_name 
from 
    information_schema.tables 
where 
    table_name = %(table)s and table_schema = %(schema)s"""

cursor.execute(query, {"table": tablename, "schema": schema})
result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```